# CryptoJS decrypt object

Tags: javascript, cryptojs

I need to decrypt something encrypted with CryptoJS. I have the function used to encrypt, the structure of the object encrypted and data used to encrypt to encrypt but i need to know some values of that object.

The function is:

```
var c = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(g.slice(0, 16));
var d = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(collectData), c, {
    iv: c,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
}).toString()
```

Later, to the encrypted variable the following is applied:

```
d.toString().replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/=/g, '*');
```

I tried with this but i cant revert the object:

```
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(coord, key, {
iv: key,
mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
```

}
);

```
console.log('decrypted clean:\n' + decrypted);
console.log('decrypted JSON.stringify():\n'+ JSON.stringify(decrypted));
```

thanks!

Comment: So you're modifying an encypted string, then expecting a decryption of it to work?  Do you attempt to reverse the replacements that are made?  Do `-`, `_` or `*` exist in the string before the replacements?  How will you tell which ones to revert back again?

Answer (score 5):

Hey your question actually help me to find a solution, encrypt takes in a object, and decrypt takes in a string, so you can do your replace

The other place that could be giving this type of error is the key, when parsing the key to Utf8 ensure that the key is exactly 16 characters you can add nulls add the end of the string to ensure it is long enough by appending '/u0000' to your string before parsing

```
encrypt(data) {
return CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(data), this.secret,
 {
    keySize: 128 / 8,
    iv: this.secret,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
  }).toString();
}

decrypt(data) {
return JSON.parse(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data,  this.secret, 
{
    keySize: 128 / 8,
    iv: this.secret,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
  })));
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution for encryption and decryption of JSON Objects.

Answer (score 0):

**Encryption and decryption of JSON object**

**Node JS**

```
var CryptoJS = require('node-cryptojs-aes').CryptoJS;

var data = {
  "glossary": {
  "title": "example glossary",
  }
}

var cip = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(data), "pass").toString();
console.log("Encrypted data = " + cip);
```

At browser side- 
**HTML**
**CDN -** "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/crypto-js@3.1.9-1/crypto-js.js"

```
var decrypted =     CryptoJS.AES.decrypt('U2FsdGVkX1/ps2tRPpM+5elyGhaT7zpp3YL45esS57GmSLoCkhcRdJDBGPUy    uvt0tf4CY6lW2+kugXocBQkc6A==', "pass");
    data = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(decrypted)
    console.log("decrypted", JSON.parse(data))
```